# AFNetworking pass data with "x-www-form-urlencoded" type

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, alamofire

[image]

In post man if I pass the data with *x-www-form-urlencoded* it will give me success response in it, but same thing I try with *afnetworking* then it does not work for me.

I know this question has already answer but some were very old and method which is used in was deprecated and some I tried but not worked for me

My code is as below

```
static func calledApi(withApiName strName:String,withParameter dictData:NSDictionary,withSuccessBlock objSuccess:successBlock,withFailureBlock objFailure:failureBlock){
        strBaseUrl = strBaseUrl.stringByAppendingString(strName)



        let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
        manager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
//        manager.requestSerializer.setQueryStringSerializationWithBlock { (request, id,error) -> String in
//            let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictData, options: .PrettyPrinted)
//            let myString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
//            return myString!
//        }
//        manager.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()
        manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()

        manager.POST(strBaseUrl, parameters: dictData, progress: { (progress) in

            }, success: { (session, responceObj) in
                let datastring : String = String(data: (responceObj as! NSData), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                print(datastring)

                var dictData = NSDictionary()
                do {
                    dictData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData((responceObj as! NSData), options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                if Int(dictData.valueForKey("code") as! String) == 1
                {
                    objSuccess(dictData)

                }
                else
                {
                    objFailure(nil, dictData.valueForKey("message") as! String)
                }

            }) { (session, error) in
                print(error)
                objFailure(error,nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: argument of the api is not reach there but post it give me success responce

Comment: `it does not work for me` do not really help us, it is hard to find the reason of failure as we can not call your api and can not reproduce the error at our end. What is the error message did you receive ? Does it come in the `failure` block instead of `success` OR api returns some business error in success block ? You should make sure you `sent parameters with correct KEY names`, also can you please double check if the response serializer should not be JSON ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless it always return me business error in success block like "Username required" but if i pass same parameter in *Post* then it gives me  success response with all the data. I am telling that you can give me proper result , I just need a guidance

Comment: Is it necessary to explicitly mention the content type ?

Comment: Try passing this value of "Content-Type" as value of "Accept". Like: `manager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")`

Comment: @NeverHopeless i find it in one solution thats why i passed it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123542/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-neverhopeless).